# GUI options with python 3.x

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

I was wondering what options are available for Python 3.x? I know Tkinter is available as well as qt, but what about the other libraries? Any word on when some of them may be ported over to 3.x?

Comment: Note that ttk is available with 3.1 also, so you get native-looking widgets instead of the more ugly-looking stuff that comes with standard Tkinter.

Answer (score 3):

Several recent versions of [PyQt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt/4.6.2) support Python 3 (I'm pointing to the PyPi entry, which is for PyQt 4.6, but there's also a more recent [PyQt 4.7](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/news/pyqt-47)).  I haven't personally tried out PyQt with Python 3, but PyQt's long been an excellent GUI toolkit so I have no reason to doubt the claim.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard really good things about WxWidgets   [or wxpython](http://www.wxpython.org/)  but cant find any word when its going to be compatible.  I always liked QT.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [newsgroups](http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/browse_thread/thread/86f8b2513941d0f4/6d77c3d4ebd0e919?lnk=gst&q=python+3) of wxPython, people ary trying to port it to Python 3.x but it will take a while.

There are also plans to port PyGTK (see the [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=566641)).

In any case, these ports will take (at least) months, I guess, so you should stick with PyQT or tkinter for the time being. Or with Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I use exclusively Tkinter, and though it's somewhat limited in terms of images, it's remarkably easy to work with and follows the standard easy-to-read Python syntax very nicely.  I'm not familiar with other GUI options, but Tkinter is great from my experience.